# Are the ideals of a ring with cyclic additive group always principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals

Note for me rings need not be unital or commutative.

> Let $R$ be a ring with cyclic additive group $(R, +, 0)$ and let $I$ be an ideal in $R$. Is $I$ principal?

Here's my attempt, **assuming $R$ has a $1$ and $1$ generates the additive group $(R,+,0)$**:

Since $(R,+,0)$ is cyclic and $(I,+,0)$ is an additive subgroup of $(R,+,0)$, it is also cyclic and generated by some $a \in R$. Best guess is $I = (a)$.

By definition, as sets $(I, +, 0 ) = (\langle a \rangle , +, 0) \subseteq (a)$ . Also if $x \in (a)$ then $x = \sum _i r_i a s_i$ for some $r_i, s_i$. Hence ( using poor notation)

$x = \sum_i r_i a (1+...+1) = \sum_i r_i (a+...+a)  \\
= \sum_i  (1+...+1) (a+...+a) = \sum_i ((a+...+a) +... +(a+...+a)) \in (\langle a \rangle, +, 0)$.

By double inclusion we have the desired equality.   $ \blacksquare$

Firstly is this correct and also what about the case where $R$ is not unital or the case where $R$ is unital but $1$ doesn't generate the additive group?

Many thanks!

**EDIT:**

For future reference. It is argued here [Does the unit generate the additive group in a unital ring with cyclic additive group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808189/does-the-unit-generate-the-additive-group-in-a-unital-ring-with-cyclic-additive?noredirect=1&lq=1) that the condition that $1$ generates the additive group is infact implied by $R$ being unital and is therefore not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Consider the ideal $8\mathbb Z$ within the ring $4\mathbb Z$.

Edit: Or, maybe this one is clearer: consider the ideal $6\mathbb Z$ within the ring $2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. $8\mathbb{Z}$ is principal in $4\mathbb{Z}$ isn't it?

Comment: What ring element would generate it?

Comment: (just to cross word limit) 8?

Comment: Within $4\mathbb Z$, the ideal $(8)=32\mathbb Z\neq 8\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Oh! Nice! I see it now, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for providing a counter example when $R$ is not unital! How about the case when $R$ is unital? Is my argument correct?

Comment: Sure, I only skimmed it, but the proof for the unital case looks good.

Comment: I suppose it is always the case that the unit generates the additive group (in the case where the group is cyclic) and this is not needed as an extra assumption? Many thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure. You could ask that as a separate question if it doesn't get enough attention here.

Comment: You've been  of great help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, an ideal is an additive subgroup of the given ring.
If the additive structure of the ideal is cyclic, then each element of the ideal can be written as $rg$, where $r\in R$ and $g$ is a generator of the additive cyclic structure.
Hence, the ideal is principal.

Comment: How do you prove the claim "If the additive structure of the ideal is cyclic, then each element of the ideal can be written as $rg$..."? This is equivalent to saying if $I$ is cyclic then it is principal, which is my question. Many thanks!

Comment: @Bellem Hmmm... it seems to me that you are mixing notation. You are using concatenation both as addition and multiplication, no?

Comment: I have been sloppy, I will answer better.